# How can i allow @onclick to handle multiple events in vueJs and make a component stay upon v-if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been stucked with this for a while. I am trying to display a few component with each click, using the same button. I have tried to work around this by creating a counter so that i can keep track of the number and v-if="this.count == 3" for the component i want to show upon clicking. However, i would want one of the component to stay and displayed and not disappear the moment the v-if becomes falsy. Is there any way that i can make the component stick after its first initialize?
The sample code is as per below;

Component to display (pls ignore the data part. Tried to change the inline style display to inline-block and unsuccessful as well.

```
<template>
  <div class="thought-box" v-if="this.count == 3">
    <h5>{{msg}}</h5>
    <div class="rating">
      <p>Rate this thought:</p>
      <b-dropdown text="Please select">
        <b-dropdown-item>Very Important</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Quite Important</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Litte Important</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>Not Important</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-dropdown>
      <a href="#">OK</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  Name: 'ThoughtBox',
  props: ['msg', 'count'],
  data(){
    return{
      activeDisplay: 'none',
      num: this.count
    }
  },
  watch: {
    num(){
      alert('this thing is working');
      this.activeDisplay = 'inlineBlock';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Base component

```
<template>
 <div class="base">
   <img src="../assets/jai-normal2.png" alt="jai_normal">
   <Convo :count="num" @handleIncrement="num++"/>
   <img src="../assets/uma-normal2.png" alt="uma_normal">
   <ThoughtBoxContainer :count="num"/>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Convo from '../components/Convo.vue'
import ThoughtBoxContainer from '../components/ThoughtBoxContainer.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Base',
  components: {
    Convo, ThoughtBoxContainer
  },
  data(){
    return {
      num: 0
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Components being reused with different props

```
<template>
<div class="thought-box-container">
  <ThoughtBox msg="Mamak and teh tarik are quick food." :count="this.count"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I'm still a kinda-fit footballer" :count="this.count"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="Dr. Michelle thinks I have pre-hypertension"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I'm not sure when I have time to take care of myself"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="Gaining weight is natural with age"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I don't want my wife to worry about my health"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="It's hard to change old habits"/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I'm embarassed to demonstrate football drills."/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="My wife thinks I'm sexy when I'm fit."/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I have to work long hours for my family's future."/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I want to be in good shape to teach my kids."/>
  <ThoughtBox msg="I can learn skills to keep me motivated to change"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ThoughtBox from "../components/ThoughtBox.vue"
export default {
  Name: 'ThoughtBoxContainer',
  components: {
    ThoughtBox
  },
  props: ["count","msg"]
}
</script>
```

Code is a bit messy cause i'm a newbie. If you have any suggestions to refactor the code, im all ears to listen and learn. 
Thank you!

Comment: so, you want the v-if to be true not just for `this.count == 3`? something like `v-if="this.count == 3 || someOtherCondition"` ?

Comment: Would `this.count >= 3` help?

Comment: @sthotakura yea that would work for one component. But if i decide to use the same component again and with different props msg, any idea if i can control that.Thanks.

Comment: if you are using the component in multiple places, then wouldn't they have their own copies of props? Or Are the props shared across the components via parent component?

Comment: I'm trying to render the same component multiple times with new props and im wondering if the v-if can help to render each of the component with every click and stay. I've edited my question earlier with the code for the components being used multiple times to see if it is of any help. Really appreciate the help, thanks.